# How can I use scanner to take input from user to choose minimum number entered?

Tags: java, runtime, int

I'm not sure where to start or how to store these values entered; the sequence of numbers being entered will be >= -90 && <= 678 and 0 will be the last number entered to terminate the program.

Comment: You need to write some code. Have you learnt how to use an if statement or a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your problem (homework?) for you, but I'm going to point you in the right direction.

First, you'll need an `ArrayList` IF you want to store the values entered, but it is not required to store them: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

This will store every value entered by the user. So how do you get values in? By using a `Scanner`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

So now your problem is trivial. You just setup a loop that has the user enter a number, and you keep a running track of the lowest number, comparing it to each number entered. You can initialize this `min` variable to your biggest possible value (678, in your case).

Comment: Thank you for the direction, I believe I'll need to use a do-while loop with an if condition. Is there a way to choose minimum without creating an array list?

Comment: Yes, as I explained above. You create a variable before you loop, call it something like `min` and set it to the maximum possible value. Then every time the user enters a number, you compare it with `min`. If it's smaller, then you set `min` equal to that number.

Comment: //     int min = console.nextInt(); 
//     while (console.hasNextInt()){
//      
//      int input = console.nextInt(); 
//     
//     
//     if (input < min){
//      
//     min = input;
//     
//     }
//     System.out.print(min);  This is where I went with it, thank you for your help